# oracle SQL procedure updating table

Tags: oracle

I need to update the the following columns in a table. males,females,infants and children using SQL procedure.from this column paxtype which has f,i,m,c.which is females,infants,males and children repectively.but am not able error  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
update xxxx a set (a.INFANTS,a.MALES,a.CHILDREN,a.FEMALES)=
(SELECT b.PAXTYPE, COUNT (b.PAXTYPE) FROM  xxxx b
(case ( count (b.PAXTYPE))
when  ( count (b.PAXTYPE))='M'then 'a.males'
when ( count (b.PAXTYPE))='F' then 'a.females'
when ( count (b.PAXTYPE))='I' then 'a.infants'
when ( count (b.PAXTYPE))='C' then 'a.children'
END)
     WHERE     a.date_key = TO_CHAR (b.FLIGHTDATE, 'RRRRMMDD')
           AND a.FLTNUM_KEY = TRIM (SUBSTR (b.flightnumber, 3))
           AND a.origin = b.frm
           AND a.destination = b.too
           --and a.date_key=20170801
           --and fightnumber = '100'
           AND TRIM (a.cancelled) IS NULL
 -- and rownum = 1 
  GROUP BY b.PAXTYPE;
```

)

Comment: i suppose, you need to get rid of `( count (b.PAXTYPE))`, next to `(case` "on the 3rd row".

Comment: have done that but the same problem

Comment: you want to update 4 column but select 3 column , also your case statment must be before from , and end of the group by there is semicolon , it doesnot to be there

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar  when i use from after the case statement i get this error     ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: You need to remove all the `count` in the `case-when` clause. The `count` function will return a number, and you are comparing it with a letter.

Comment: @MagdielAybar in need a number

Comment: @AbelYator you can't compare a number to a letter. If you need a number then compare to a number e.g. `count (b.PAXTYPE) = 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a total count of each type, right? I think this is what you want to do.

```
update xxxx a set (a.INFANTS,a.MALES,a.CHILDREN,a.FEMALES)=
(SELECT 
    sum(case when b.PAXTYPE = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) as infants_count,
    sum(case when b.PAXTYPE = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as males_count,
    sum(case when b.PAXTYPE = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as children_count,
    sum(case when b.PAXTYPE = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as females_count
FROM  xxxx b
     WHERE     a.date_key = TO_CHAR (b.FLIGHTDATE, 'RRRRMMDD')
           AND a.FLTNUM_KEY = TRIM (SUBSTR (b.flightnumber, 3))
           AND a.origin = b.frm
           AND a.destination = b.too
           --and a.date_key=20170801
           --and fightnumber = '100'
           AND TRIM (a.cancelled) IS NULL
 -- and rownum = 1 
  GROUP BY b.PAXTYPE);
```